# Angular universal with node and spring boot behind nginx?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, angular-universal

I've been searching for information on how to use Angular Universal with a Spring Boot backend. I found a library that delegates the request through Spring Boot to Node.

https://github.com/swaechter/angularj-universal

But I'm wondering if there would be any problems with putting Nginx (or similar) in front of both Node and Spring Boot and using it to proxy '/api' requests to Spring and everything else to Node.

There doesn't seem to be anyone suggesting this approach in blogs, stackoverflow, etc. Am I missing something?

Comment: Any updates on subject?

Comment: Hi Roman, I gave it a try and it seemed to work fine. I'm not doing much with Universal for now.